# Django, I am getting "Permission Denied" when trying to access a directory that is given to an ftp user

Tags: linux, django, ftp, proftpd

My django application (v1.8) is using a directory for exporting some csv files. This directory is something like: "/home/username/django_project/csv_out".

I have intentionally chmod the "csv_out" dir to 777.

My partner wanted to access this directory in order to download and inspect those csv files.

I created an FTP user like this:

```
useradd ftp_user -p somepassword -d /home/username/django_project/csv_out/ -s /bin/false
```

Since then I get a "Permission Denied" error **from Django** (was not getting that error before): The FTP Server is giving access to the folder without problem. Django "misbehaves".

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/username/django_project/csv_out/weights_1.csv'
```

Am I doing something wrong?

PS: I am using proftpd ftp server

Comment: Why FTP servers even bother to ask for a username and passwords is a real mystery.

Comment: Are you getting the "Permission denied" error when uploading files, or when downloading files?

Comment: I am getting the "Permission Denied" error, from Django when it tries to access the directory, not the ftp server. The FTP server works fine. It allows access to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

You also need +x (search) permission on /home/username and /home/username/django_project/ directories for ftp_user

Try this

```
 chmod a+x /home/username
 chmod a+x /home/username/django_project/
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that today, and report back.

Comment: I am sorry, it didn't work. Actually the problem is with django, not linux. Django is giving me the "permission denied" so, I need to do something with the django settings or proftpd configuration (somehow revoke access for this folder or something similar)

Answer (score 0):

note your ftp user is different from your website user.
which user account you started your django website?

Comment: You have a point. The owner of the directory "csv_out" is the user "soulman". It is the user that I use to log in to the system and work. I did not want to give this user's password to my partner and mess with things. So I tried to create another user to connect through ftp and have access only to this directory. There must be some conflict there as I see it. Is there any simple workaround for this?